# Compile Email application from AOSP

Tags: android, git

I would like to add some features to the AOSP Email application which is not supported anymore. So I cloned the repository [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email) (which is a Eclipse project) and migrated it to a Gradle project in Android Studio. But after that it comes to thousend Java errors, missing resources and so on...

So has Google really a not working repo there? Do I maybe need some other repos from AOSP? As it is for now I can't work with it anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I cloned the repository here (which is a Eclipse project) and migrated it to a Gradle project in Android Studio.

None of the AOSP projects are designed to be used this way. They are designed to be built as part of a firmware build.

If your objective is to contribute changes back to the AOSP, you will need to follow [their instructions for using their source code](http://source.android.com/source/index.html).

If your objective was to create your own email app, you may be better served starting with some base that is buildable as a regular Android app (e.g., K-9 Mail). Otherwise, you are going to need to fix all of those problems, as they reference things that are not going to be available to your app project via the Android SDK.

Comment: Okay thank you for this answer. So there is no "easy" chance to create it as standalone application?

Comment: @Cilenco: No. There might be a few AOSP apps that hew pretty close to the SDK, avoiding internal references. AFAIK, Email isn't one of them.