# How to import an Android Studio project from android.googlesource.com?

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-gradle-plugin, google-source-repositories

I'm trying to open the DeskClockApp (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) in my version of Android Studio. However, since no gradle files are downloaded, Android Studio is struggling to see the project as an Android-Gradle app.

I've tried downloading the source code as a zip, importing it as Git from Android Studio's VCS, etc. The online repository doesn't have the gradle files b/c the developer added a gitignore for gradle (makes sense). I also considered adding the gradle files myself but the project structure seems to be slightly different than the structure defined online. When I first import that project it says Android Framework detected, however, on configuring it for Android it cannot find any module to run, or even display the correct files (in the Project view). Is there any way to generate the correct gradle files for this? Maybe run it without gradle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39689796/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare is there anyway to open this project in a way in which I can see the layout files in a graphics view? The only reason I was trying to open the project was to try and see how the layout for the alarms were being created. Since we can't clone and open these apps without doing way too much, is there an easier way to open the layout files?

Comment: Well, the layout files are just XML files, so you can read them in your favorite text editor. If you specifically are looking for Android Studio's designer or preview... try creating an empty Android Studio project, then copying in all of the resources from the DeskClock app into that empty project. Adjust the project's activity's manifest entry to refer to whatever theme DeskClock's activity is using. Then, see if you can get Android Studio to show you the layouts with working previews.