# How do I get Google's open source apps (android.googlesource.com) running on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, open-source

In other news, I **spent half a day** - being a beginner and all -  trying to import [DeskClock](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock) into Android Studio, so I could study it better, instead of crawling dozens of source code files.
Cloning [the project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/) didn't work out, what with missing gradle files, and Android Studio not recognising it as an Android app, therefore not loading necessary configurations that'd enable one to run it.

Next line of action was to try creating an Android project, deleting `MainActivity.java` & `activity_main.xml`; copying over files from [DeskClock (com.android.deskclock)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+archive/refs/heads/master.tar.gz), making necessary refactoring to avoid `provider` & package name conflicts. Did so and upon running the app, I got errors here and there, related to missing dependencies, which I added and tried running again; app installs, but keeps crashing due to errors I attribute to `multiDex` being disabled; I enabled it (via build.gradle, by setting `multiDexEnabled` to `true`, extending `MultiDexApplication` in [DesktopClockApplication](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/deskclock/DeskClockApplication.kt) instead of `Application`), but still face the error::

```
E/hengnet.decloc: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.blogspot.thengnet.declock, PID: 22671
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.blogspot.thengnet.declock.deskclock.DeskClockApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.blogspot.thengnet.declock.deskclock.DeskClockApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.blogspot.thengnet.declock-rXBKN9OfqNprzSTBu6qqMg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.blogspot.thengnet.declock-rXBKN9OfqNprzSTBu6qqMg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

What is the way IN?
What do I need to set up to get Google's open source apps running?!

Inspiration: [How to import an Android Studio project from android.googlesource.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57082245/how-to-import-an-android-studio-project-from-android-googlesource-com)

My purpose it to build a decent scheduling app for Alarm & Calendar, so anything besides would play out anyway. Thanks!

Comment: No easy solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689385/compile-email-application-from-aosp/39689796#39689796

Comment: So it would seem...